# Adding Custom-Headers and send it to the Back-end service using AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

I have a requirement where, when I hit an API endpoint `(say GET https://XXX.XXX.domain.com/ama/api/v1/getdata)`, the request has to reach the AWS API Gateway. In API Gateway, I wish to add an custom-header to the request and send it to the back-end service (LB) based on the below conditions:

1. If the URL `(https://XXX.XXX.domain.com/ama/api/v1/getdata)`, contains the keyword `ama`, then add a custom-header to the request like, `service: ama`.
2. Also, I want the keyword `ama` to be removed from  the URL and sent to the back-end service with just `/api/v1/getdata`

Is the above scenario is possible with AWS API Gateway?

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact use case for Integration and Method Transformations. Look into this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/rest-api-data-transformations.html

This will give you a starting point on how to add headers dynamically based on the information in the request, as well as have the end point modified ala your second point.